# Using Running service results in activity

Tags: java, android, service, android-activity

In my service values are updated every 1 sec . The running activity runs once so I can't update textviews or functions with new results and updates .tried to use timer in activity :

```
 Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate( 
               new java.util.TimerTask() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                       if(Serve.Connecting){
                             tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                                tv.setText("Connecting");
                                ProgressBar PB =  (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
                                PB.setProgress(25);
                        }
                        if(Serve.Connected){
                             tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                                tv.setText("Connected");
                                ProgressBar PB =  (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
                                PB.setProgress(50);
                        }
                        if(Serve.Connected && Serve.loading.FALSE){
                             tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                                tv.setText("Loading");
                             ProgressBar PB =  (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
                            PB.setProgress(75);
                        }
                        if(Serve.Connected && Serve.loading){
                             tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                                tv.setText("Done");
                                ProgressBar PB =  (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
                                PB.setProgress(100);
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Loadingpage.this, Setup.class);
                                 startActivity(intent);
                                 finish();
                                 frstscr=false;

                        } 



           }},
           200, 500
           );
```

but It didn't work so I tried using that handler example :

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();
runnable.run();

    private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() 
{

public void run() 
{
     //
     // Do the stuff
     //

     handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
}};
```

but didn't work , any Ideas ??
I even used while(frstscrn){fun } where frstscrn is boolean that identifies that the activity is running

Comment: did you call handler.post(runnable) ?

Comment: isn't it by calling the line runnable.run(); ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your activity will look something like this ..

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GenerateBroadcastActivity extends Activity 
{
    Button bt ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.generate_broadcast);

        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt1);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyNewService.class));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("BROADCAST_UNIQUE_NAME"));
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

             //take out data from intent
              int progressValue = intent.getIntExtra("progressValue",0);

             // just for instance , you can set the progress in your progress bar //defined globally in your app 
              progressBar.setProgress(progressValue);  

            Toast.makeText(context, "Broadcast coming with Progress value" + progressValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();          
        }
    };
}
```

Write your service class like this ...

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyNewService extends IntentService 
{

    public MyNewService()
    {
      super("Service Name");    
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) 
    {
       //Do some background task . 
          int progressValue = 20 ;

       //Send broadcast like this
        Intent broadcast = new Intent();
       // name should be same as specified in your activity class onResume method
        broadcast.setAction("BROADCAST_UNIQUE_NAME");
       //send extra data with your broadcast   
       broadcast.putExtra("progressValue",progressValue);
       //send it now
       sendBroadcast(broadcast); 
    }
}
```

This broadcast wil be received by your broadcast receiver and you will get a message on screen. Refer this link for basics : http://www.edureka.in/blog/android-tutorials-broadcast-receivers/

Comment: so I have to change the service to an IntentService , I'm going to try this .......thank a lot

Comment: It will work even if you are using a Service instead of IntentService. You change the type depending on your requirement. IntentService simply stops after excecuting the code inside onHandleIntent() whereas the Service might keep running depending on the return value given inside the onStartCommand() method . for example : return STICKY ;

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm using service because I need it to be running all the time and repeated

Answer (score 0):

Have a Intent in your activity and register it through code.

From your service, send the updated value by broadcasting the intent and then from `onReceive()` update the value to a UI component

Comment: sorry but I'm new to android would You plz show me a simple example .. thanks in advance